# SQL How to find and sum set of maximums in an order set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to find a way to select and sum the localized maximums from an ordered set.
So, given the following ordered data:

```
HardwareID  Timestamp               Odometer
ABC123      2013-10-28 07:47:20     300
ABC123      2013-09-25 16:40:43     250
ABC123      2013-09-11 16:33:31     200
ABC123      2013-08-08 09:03:52     120
ABC123      2013-08-05 07:52:58     80
ABC123      2013-07-22 07:42:34     30
ABC123      2013-07-03 11:47:55     140
ABC123      2013-06-25 17:27:20     100
ABC123      2013-06-13 12:01:18     50
ABC123      2013-06-11 07:59:50     10
```

I would like a query to pull out and sum the two local maximums (300 + 140):

```
HardwareID Odometer
ABC123     440
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169280/sql-query-help-finding-a-local-maximum) sliding window approach but could not get it working for my scenario. Is there a common way of solving this type of problem (looping over a set and comparing against previous values)?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 and beyond has the `lead()` and `lag()` functions that are a great help for this.

```
select HardwareId, sum(odometer)
from (select t.*,
             lag(Odometer) over (partition by HardwareId order by TimeStamp) as prevo,
             lead(Odometer) over (partition by HardwareId order by TimeStamp) as nexto
      from table t
     ) t
where Odometer > coalesce(prevo, 0) and Odometer > coalesce(nexto, 0);
```

You can do this is pre-2012 versions, but the syntax is a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Although I'm on 2008, this solution has guided me in the right direction and I think I have a way to pull this off in 2008 now.

Answer (score 0):

I added a sequential identity to your test data to make this example easier, but I assume you have a primary key on your side to leverage (if not row_number over the timestamp will work as well).

In this example I am simply joining to the "next sequential" row and evaluating if it is great than / or not.  If so, I consider it a peak and use in the subsequent sum.

Hopefully you can use this to adapt on your side.

```
declare @t table (Pk int identity(1,1), HardwareID varchar(10), [Timestamp] datetime, Odometer int);
insert into @t
    select 'ABC123', '2013-10-28 07:47:20', 300 union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-09-25 16:40:43', 250  union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-09-11 16:33:31', 200  union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-08-08 09:03:52', 120  union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-08-05 07:52:58', 80   union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-07-22 07:42:34', 30   union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-07-03 11:47:55', 140  union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-06-25 17:27:20', 100  union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-06-13 12:01:18', 50   union all
    select 'ABC123', '2013-06-11 07:59:50', 10;

--to illustrate
select  a.HardwareId,
        a.Odometer,
        [IsAPeak] = case when a.Odometer > isnull(b.Odometer, 0) then 1 else 0 end
from    @t a
left
join    @t b on 
        a.pk = b.pk+1 and
        a.HardwareId = b.HardwareId;

select  a.HardwareId,
        sum(case when a.Odometer > isnull(b.Odometer, 0) then a.Odometer else 0 end)
from    @t a
left
join    @t b on 
        a.pk = b.pk+1 and
        a.HardwareId = b.HardwareId
group
by      a.HardwareId;
```